# Use variable name table as pool for content access

Tags: php, mysql

I want to access text from my database based on a variable table created for text posted for each month. Here is the code I have:

mybq_post_txt_act.php (relevant parts)-

```
$month=date('m');
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="user"; // Mysql username 
$password="pass"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="db"; // Database name 
$tbl_name_m="mybq_post_txt_main"; // Table name (main)
$tbl_name_p="mybq_post_txt_"."$month"; // table name (pool)


// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

//create variable table
$sql_c = 

"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mybq_post_txt`.`$month` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `message` varchar(160) NOT NULL,
  `tag` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=229";
mysql_query($sql_c);


// Get values from form 
$user=mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['myusername']);
$myusername=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['myusername']);
$mypassword=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['mypassword']);
$mymessage=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['mymessage']);
$mytag=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['mytag']);

    if ((!empty($mymessage)) && (!empty($mytag)))
             {

// Insert data into mysql 
$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name_m (username, message, tag, date)VALUES('$user', '$mymessage', '$mytag', CURDATE())";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name_p (username, message, tag, date)VALUES('$user', '$mymessage', '$mytag', CURDATE())";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

             }

// if successfully insert data into database, displays message "Successful". 
if($result){
echo "<div class='center2'><font color='green'>Congratulations! Your post was Successful!</div>";
echo "<BR>";

}

else {
echo "<div class='center2'><font color='red'>You have one or more Invalid Entries. Your Post was not successful.</div>";
echo "<br>";
echo "<div class='center2'><font color='red'>Please go <a href='mybq-post-txt.php'>back</a> and try again.</div>";
echo "<br>";

}





}

else {
echo "<div class='center2'><font color='red'>Wrong Captcha. Your Post was not successful.</div>";
echo "<br>";
echo "<div class='center2'><font color='red'>Please go <a href='mybq-post-txt.php'>back</a> and try again.</div>";
echo "<br>";

}

?>
</div></td></tr>
<?php echo "<tr><td><div class='center2'><a href='mybq-index.php'>MyBQuotes main</a></div></td> <td><a href='mybq-post-txt.php'>Post Another</a></div></td></tr>"; ?>

</table>
 </body> </html>
<? ob_flush();//Flush buffer output ?>
```

I keep getting my custom error: "You have one or more Invalid Entries. Your Post was not successful."

Can you help?

Comment: `echo mysql_error();` after `$result` to check why your query was unsuccessful

Comment: *Why* are you attempting to partition your data in this way?  It is a terribly bad practice in violation of the [Principle of Orthogonal Design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_Orthogonal_Design).  You should simply have a single table, with a column that identifies the month; if there is a *legitimate* requirement to partition the data (e.g. for storage or performance reasons) then you should use MySQL's native [partitioning](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/partitioning.html) support rather than trying to bake your own.

Comment: However, in the vast majority of cases, partitioning is completely unnecessary as suitable indexing will more than suffice.

Comment: @'cheezburger': "Table 'db.mybq_post_txt_03' doesn't exist"

Comment: @adeoba In your create table code 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mybq_post_txt`.`$month`' you are missing an `_` in the table name

Comment: yes that did the trick, although i had to resort to using $tbl_name_p instead. Thanks.